# How to find the inverse of CDF of geometric function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

The cdf of geometric distribution is given by $ F(x)=1-(1-p)^x$.
I want to calculate the inverse of it, for example, $F^{-1}(U)$

I am doing the following

```
f[x_] := 1 - (1 - p)^x;  InverseFunction[f[u]]
```

But I do not get anything.

my ultimate goal is to generate sample of a random variable that has geometric distribution.

Comment: Hand calculating: y==1-(1-p)^x; Log[1-y]==x Log[1-p]; x= Log[1-y]/Log[1-p]

Comment: or `Solve[y == f[x], x]`

Comment: You need `InverseFunction[f]` not `InverseFunction[f[u]]`, and it returns `Log[1 - #1]/Log[1 - p] &`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`GeometricDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeometricDistribution.html) is built-in

```
dist[p_] = GeometricDistribution[p];

PDF[dist[p], x]

(* Piecewise[{{(1 - p)^x*p, x >= 0}}, 0] *)

CDF[dist[p], q]

(* Piecewise[{{1 - (1 - p)^(1 + Floor[q]), q >= 0}}, 0] *)

DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist[p]]

(* 0 < p <= 1 *)
```

Random samples from the distribution can be generated using [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html)

```
Manipulate[samples = RandomVariate[dist[p], 1000];
 {min, max} = MinMax[samples];
 Column[{
   Show[
    Histogram[samples, Automatic, "PDF"],
    DiscretePlot[PDF[dist[p], x], {x, min, max},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]],
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    AxesLabel -> {x, PDF}],
   Show[
    Histogram[samples, Automatic, "CDF"],
    DiscretePlot[CDF[dist[p], x], {x, min, max},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]],
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    AxesLabel -> {x, CDF}]}],
 {{p, 0.5}, 0.01, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

However, if you want to use [`InverseCDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html)

```
samples2 = InverseCDF[dist[1/2], #] & /@ RandomReal[1, 1000];

Show[
 Histogram[samples2, Automatic, "PDF"],
 DiscretePlot[PDF[dist[1/2], x], {x, min, max},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]],
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 AxesLabel -> {x, PDF}]
```

[image]